# Jackson`s ObjectMapper fails: socket closed

Tags: java, jackson, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache's `HttpClient` to initiate a task like this:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

This request contains an id for identifying the task related to the request. I extract it using Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
JobStatusModel status = mapper.readValue(entity.getContent(), JobStatusModel.class);
String taskId = status.getId();
```

This works without issue, I have used it many times throughout my code. I can extract `taskId` this way, without any issue and determine when the task is finished using repeated calls a different REST API for task status.

The error occurs when I try to extract the results of the finished task. This is done with a similar request to a different URL:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
JobResultModel status = mapper.readValue(entity2.getContent(), JobResultModel.class);
request.releaseConnection();
```

This last line fails with a very useless exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
```

I have tried many ways to read the response entity to see what is wrong. I have tried the exact same call using `Postman` and it was successful without issue. The error has nothing to do with an incorrect form of `JobResultModel`. With the configuration `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` for `ObjectMapper`, it should even be allowing mistakes anyways.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does it actually fails on `request.releaseConnection`? Do you release connection in successful scenario above?

Comment: It fails on the line `JobResultModel status = mapper.readValue(entity2.getContent(), JobResultModel.class)`

Comment: Usually it's best practice to post the full stacktrace. I assume Mapper tries to read from Inputstream backed by socked, and that socket end up being closed.

Maybe wrap `entity2.getContent()` into some debuggable filterstream, to peek at contents and bytes that were actually processed before the failure.